# how to move SP calendar list event from one date to another using javascript?

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-calendar

I want to drag and drop an event in a SP calendar list from one date/time to another date / time, how can i do that? Here I am creating one app related with some vehicle stuff, there I want to drag and drop the event into a different  time sections and then there i want to move the event according to time zone like below snap
[image]

When I am dragging that red coloured cell and dropping to any white coloured cell then that event's time should got changed, can any one guide me with this?

Comment: 2 steps - 1. add eventhandlers for drag & drop and 
2. on drop identify the dragged event-item (maybe there is an ID in the html) and change it's date via JSOM. 

A event-item is nothing more than a list item in sharepoint and you will find plenty of ressources on how to do that.